# Batch File - Depending/Ordering Actions

Tags: batch-file

I need to execute two diferent actions in a batch file but I want the second action only run IF the result of the first action run. It’s possible to order the actions in a batch file?
My question is because the second action It will be carried by the first action data so it depends on the success of the first action.

How can I do that in a Batch file?

Comment: See answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564). Hopefully the first executed application or command exits with a value greater 0 if not successful. For example the command __del__ always exits with value `0` even if there was no file to delete or deletion of a specified file failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&&` operator to join the two commands and only run the second if the first was successful.

```
echo This always runs && echo This only runs if the previous command was successful.
```

You can also use `||` to only run the second command if the first fails.

```
echo This runs first || echo This is a bad example since echo always runs, but if the first command failed for some reason, this would be displayed.
```